# Catch WCF FaultException in Client running on Mono

Tags: wcf, mono

I have a server/client that uses NetTcp duplex channel and I'm trying to figure out how much work is required to run it under mono (v2.10.8).

Can someone tell me how to correctly throw a FaultException to a client that runs under mono?? Or if this isn't fully supported?

The contract is defined as:

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = true)]
[FaultContract(typeof(IOException))] 
string ConnectWithFault(string clientVersion, string workstation)
```

and the server side method will always generate the fault for testing purposes:

```
public string ConnectWithFault(string clientVersion, string workstation)
{
  IOException ioe = new IOException("Testing Fault Contract");
  throw new FaultException<IOException>(ioe, new FaultReason(ioe.Message), new FaultCode("Sender")); 

  return "Should Never Reach Here!";
}
```

Everything works fine when I run the client normally in windowns, but when I run the client in mono command prompt in Windows, the FaultException does seem to come through to the client, but I’m not able to catch it properly. Or is there an internal mono error when it’s trying to catch the FaultException on the client side?? I’ve tried to catch is in a few different guises:

```
public void TestConnectWithFault()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Client->TestConnectWithFault() +");
  try
  {
    string response = RemoteSessionChannel.ConnectWithFault("client1.0", "MY-PC");
    Console.WriteLine("**** DuplexClient->Connect Response: {0}", response);
  }
  catch (FaultException<IOException> ioe)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Connect failed. (IOException): {0}", ioe.ToString());
  }
  catch (FaultException fe)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Connect failed. (FaultException): {0}", fe.ToString());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Connect failed. (Exception): {0}", ex.ToString());
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Client->TestConnectWithFault() -");
}
```

But I always just get the following output in the client console and the client hangs:

```
Client->TestConnectWithFault() +

**System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Testing Fault Contract
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.DuplexClientRuntimeChannel.ProcessInputCor
e (IInputChannel input, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.DuplexClientRuntimeChannel.ProcessInput (I
InputChannel input, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message) [0x00000] in <
filename unknown>:0**
```

So it looks like the exception is coming across to the client, but isn't getting picked up by any of the catch blocks, or have I not got this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been [bug #7177](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7177) that I fixed in Mono last week.

I quickly [tested this](https://github.com/baulig/Provcon-Faust/tree/034df9622bcd772fcc8547a8931c60d7e319807d/TestWCF) and it's working fine now.